# cp cannot access the files in a directorty

Tags: file-copy

I have a script that copies the missing files from one machine to another. The code is

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MACHINE=machine2
DIRECTORY=/test/oracle/

rsh $MACHINE "cd /test/oracle/" 

scp -rp machine2:/test/oracle/miss_files machine1:/test/oracle


cd /test/oracle/MT ; ls -ltrh  > /tset/oracle/MT_extract_machine1


diff /test/oracle/MT_extract_machine1 /test/oracle/miss_files > /test/oracle/diffo

awk '{print$10}' /test/oracle/diff0 >  /test/oracle/diffr

while read -r line ; do scp -rp  $line /test/oracle/final_result ; done <  /test/oracle/diffr
```

Comment: 1. What kind of errors? Permission errors? Check them - no one here has access to your devices. 2. Why don't you use `rsync`? Looks like your solution is quite convoluted and doesn't take into consideration that files on the source machine may have changed.

Comment: hint: you're writing a shell script; there's literally no reason to put multiple commands on a single line separated by `;`. That only hurts readability!

Comment: Actually, I want to copy the contents of diffr file into directory /test/oracle/final_result .when the script is executed, The output is cp :cannot access file1 cp:cannot access file3. permission of files and all directory are 777. The result is saved in the diffr file but not copied to the final_result directory.

Comment: Please add the output of the script to your question. Also, `777` is a terrible idea for permission set and almost certainly not the problem.

Comment: Your first executable line uses `rsh` (really? Why not `ssh`) to cd to a directory and then immediately exit. What is the purpose of this line? Your last pipeline started with `read` will break if there's whitespace in any file names. Make sure you set IFS first to avoid problems.

Comment: If you have clarifications, please add these to the question, not in the comments. At the moment, the question does not attempt to describe the issue that you have in any way. If you get error messages, consider including them without modification in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing cd ... followed by ls, so you're not getting the path, only the filenames.
So scp does not have the whole path, when you hit the scp -rp $line ...
Seems like you need to do scp -rp /test/oracle/$line ...

Comment: Did you also spot the `tset` misspelling?  The thing you are commenting on is not necessarily the main issue...